# How can a (global) Python module be created within a function with the module name specified as an argument of the function?

Tags: python, function, module, global

I want to create a global module object within a function with the name of the module specified as an argument of the function. I have attempted to do this in the following way:

```
import imp

def function1(moduleLocalName):
    exec("global " + moduleLocalName)
    moduleString = "bar = 3"
    exec(moduleLocalName + " = imp.new_module(\"" + moduleLocalName + "\")")
    exec moduleString in globals()[moduleLocalName].__dict__

function1("foo")
print(foo.bar)
```

The module seems to be created successfully in the scope of the function, but it is then not available outside the scope of the function. Note that I do not want to simply return the module object from the function, setting it to an existing global object; I want to create the global module object *within* the function. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best:

```
import sys, types

def function1(moduleLocalName):
    m = types.ModuleType(moduleLocalName)
    setattr(m, 'bar', 3)
    sys.modules[moduleLocalName] = m
    return m

foo = function1('foo')
```

Any other module can now `import foo` as we've stuck it in `sys.modules`.

Key lesson: **don't** use `exec`.  You don't really need it.  If you think you need it, you may likely be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights on this. It's not exactly what I want, but it is a reasonable approach. You're right about ```exec``` in this specific case. For me, I'm using it in a larger piece of code that builds a module object using a string of code.